# How to expalin the ouput order of try-catch in Java?

Tags: java, try-catch

I find an interesting case:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a =0;
        int b = 2;
        int c = 10;
        int d = 0;
        int e = 0;

        try {
            d=c/b;
            e=b/a;
        }catch (ArithmeticException ex){
            System.out.println("TEST");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println(d);
    }
```

There will be two kinds of printing order:

1

```
TEST
java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
    at Chapter10.Test2.main(Test2.java:14)
5
```

2

```
java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
    at Chapter10.Test2.main(Test2.java:14)
TEST
5
```

But when I comment the line `System.out.println("TEST");`,there will be only one order:

```
5
java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
    at Chapter10.Test2.main(Test2.java:14)
```

So I want to ask what's the order of the executed order of try-catch block? Why is the `System.out.println(d);` executed before `catch` block when the exception happens?

Comment: Don't forget that `System.out` and `System.err` are different outputs that might get flushed at different times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`printStackTrace` writes to `System.err`, which is a diifferent stream than `System.out`. Change your code to `ex.printStackTrace(System.out)` for a consistent output.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a =0;
    int b = 2;
    int c = 10;
    int d = 0;
    int e = 0;

    try {
        d=c/b;
        e=b/a;
    }catch (ArithmeticException ex){
        System.out.println("TEST");
        ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
    }

    System.out.println(d);
}
```

Will yield

> TEST
>
> java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
>
> at Chapter10.Test2.main(Test2.java:18)
>
> 5

As expected.

Answer (score 1):

By default, `Exception.printStackTrace()` uses `System.err` as `PrintStream`, which is not the same with `System.out`. So the order of code execution:

```
System.out.println("TEST");
ex.printStackTrace();
System.out.println(d);
```

might be inconsistent with the actual output. For certain, `5` will be printed after `TEST`. The exception message might be printed:

- before `TEST`
- between `TEST` and `5`
- after `5`.

Comment: @downvoters please let me know where I got it wrong :)

Answer (score 1):

you nead to use with "System.out" instead of "printStackTrace()".